# Adding a view between TabBarController & NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, subview

I have a tab bar controller with each of its view controllers a navigation controller. I want to block some of the views within one of the navs (AlertView style) with a black transparent view, which should cover the nav bar at the top, without it covering the tab bar at the bottom. So, if you look at the docs (Views of a Tab Bar Controller - Figure 2) I want to completely cover the custom content nav bar included.

I don't personally believe there's an easy solution to this, any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the AlertViewStyle from one of the UIViewController then you should try this code:

```
  //you can replace the UIView with a custom UIView class
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.view.frame.size.height)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; // set your desired color
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:view];
```

Comment: I've added this code, and it works fine for the initial issue, except now the view added to the navBar isn't receiving any touches at all. I've tried hitTest (fires on the nav bar and tab bar but not my subview), touchesBegan, pointInside...

Comment: Do you add other UIViews on the navigationController.view ? Maybe you can add the code where you add the UIView to the navigationContrller.view.

Comment: It's very hard to find the problem because I don't rely know where you are adding the view. I just tested the code and I added a UITapGestureRecognizer on the view that is being added to navController.view and it's working ok.

Comment: I'm adding the view in the viewDidLoad of the contentView, I'll try moving it and adding it after the initWithRoot:

Comment: You have to add the view to the navigationController.view in the -(void)viewDidLoad method of UIViewController that is the root of your navigationController.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I was adding it as a subview of the navigation bar, instead of controller.view, I'll add the tap now.

Comment: It's fine now, turns out I had it configured wrong in the xib so it wasn't linking the actions up. Thanks for your help!